# Conjugate Functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show the following:

By considering df and dg, show that the curves f(x,y)=0 and g(x,y)=0 intersect at right angles provided f and g are conjugate functions.

I have tried to use the definition of conjugate functions for 2 variables and am guessing that you have to use this to show that the gradients at the intersection point(s) are negative reciprocals of one another?

Answer (score 1):

Saying the gradients are negative reciprocals of each other makes no sense, because the gradients are *vectors*. It's enough to show the *slopes* of the tangents to the level sets are negative reciprocals.

Which is the same as saying the gradients are orthogonal: $$f_xg_x+f_yg_y=0.$$Which in turn is clear from the Cauchy-Riemann equations.